# Fetching json from PHP using Ajax Call in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I have a json encoded result from my database query, I want to call the results on my html page but my ajax call isn't working? please ignore the URL for ajax I changed it to test but I have the right URL here.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "http://test.com/john/retrieve.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
    return false;

});
</script>
```

```html
$sql = "SELECT f_name, l_name, phone, email, street_address, suburb, comments FROM unquoted";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$json = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      
        // echo "First Name: " . $row["f_name"]. " - Last Name: " . $row["l_name"]. " Phone " . $row["phone"].  " Email " . $row["email"]. " Street Address " . $row["street_address"]. " Suburb " . $row["suburb"]. " Comments " . $row["comments"]."<br>" ;
     array_push($json, array($row['f_name'], $row['l_name'], $row['phone'], $row['email'], $row['street_address'], $row['suburb'], $row['comments']));

    }
     echo json_encode($json);

} else {

    echo "0 results";

}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Is there something showing on console window? Also, can you use "Network" tab on the developer tools to see if the Ajax request is being done?